# Visual studio 2013 installation failing "Element not found"

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

The install fails with an "Element not found" error.

[image]

Lin the log file, first, there are a bunch of "registry key not found" messages:

```
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCore86'; variable = 'compilerCore86D11_Ver'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCore'; variable = 'compilerCoreD11_Inst'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'compilerCoreD11_Inst' to value 0
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCore'; variable = 'compilerCoreD11_Ver'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCoreWP80'; variable = 'compilerCoreWP80_Inst'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'compilerCoreWP80_Inst' to value 0
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCoreWP80'; variable = 'compilerCoreWP80_Ver'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\CompilerX64Arm'; variable = 'compilerx64arm_DetectKeyExists'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'compilerx64arm_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\CompilerX64Nat'; variable = 'compilerx64nat_DetectKeyExists'
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'compilerx64nat_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[1AB8:1ABC][2014-08-13T20:22:33]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\CompilerX64X86';
```

Then there are some errors about not finding public keys:

```
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e310: Failed to verify payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]i000: MUX:  Verify Failed.  Retry acquiring, Retry Count: 1 of 3
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023728 (0x80070490), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Verify, Package Id=Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e314: Failed to cache payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 from working path: C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Temp\{ec85bfda-a752-4fe6-b9ad-f4c42d6ff44b}\Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, error: 0x80070490.
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e349: Application requested retry of payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, encountered error: 0x80070490. Retrying...
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]i338: Acquiring package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, copy from: C:\Users\William\Downloads\packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_x86\BuildTools_MSBuild.msi
[1AB8:0818][2014-08-13T20:23:38]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[1A80:1AD8][2014-08-13T20:23:38]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
```

Answer (score 1):

See if below solutions work or not.

Mount the iso with any virtual cd software
Copy the mounted content to a local folder, e.g. C:\temp\vs2013\
Run “vs_ultimate.exe” from the local folder